# Пересылка сообщений telethon python - как при пересылке указывать на какое сообщение отвечает пользователь?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Собираю сообщения с чужой группы в свой канал. При пересылке использую библиотеку telethon, пересылаю через forward_message. При этом в мой канал пересылается имя пользователя и текст его сообщения.

Сложность в том, что в моем канале я не вижу на какое сообщение отвечает тот или иной пользователь.

Есть ли возможность пересылать сообщения, чтобы было видно кому отвечает пользователь?

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chats))
async def news(event):
     await client.forward_messages(my_chats, event.message)
```